# Trouble with deleting a column in a dataframe based on the index of the column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There seems to be a logical error. When I run the code, **the last column is not removed**.

---

Any help is appreciated

```
A = [['Roy', 80, 75, 85, 90, 95, 0],
     ['John', 75, 80, 75, 85, 100, 0],
     ['Dave', 80, 80, 80, 90, 95, 0]]
A = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

### Here  I do some operations to identify

```
 # Remove columns that meet a certain criteria.
 # This statement does not seem to be working because
 # at the end I get the same matrix without removing any column
A.drop(A.columns[i], axis=1)
```

Comment: A=A.drop(A.columns[i], axis=1)  just need to assign it back

Answer (score 1):

As @Wen already showed: you need to reassign the results.

```
A = A.drop(A.columns[i], axis=1)
```

you can also do it in place without reassigning:

```
A.drop(A.columns[i], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Use `A = A.loc[:, A.ne(0).any()]`

Comment: I was using     if np.all(A.iloc[:, j] == temp):
        A.drop(A.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)

Answer (score 1):

Assign it back to A:

```
A = A.drop(A.columns[i], axis=1)
```

or use inplace option:

```
A.drop(A.columns[i], axis=1, inplace =True)
```